# Should the Help Center "Stack Exchange"'s be replaced with "Stack Overflow"?

Tags: discussion, help-center, company

As said in the [Company's name change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) blog post (emphasis mine):

> In the weeks ahead, we’ll **change the name of things like the blog,
> podcast, and any other places where “Stack Exchange” was referring to
> the company**, as opposed to the network of Q&A sites. Our Q&A sites
> will still be collectively known as the Stack Exchange Network.

Are lines like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans):

> Stack Exchange cannot lift answer bans by request.

referring to *the company* or *network of sites*? I *think* they're referring the company there, so should that be changed to:

> Stack Overflow cannot lift answer bans by request.

?

*If* this should be replaced, then there are probably more places in the help center that should be changed.

Comment: In short, it boils down to "no, it shouldn't change". :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the find! Although I'm not sure I completely understand the reasoning behind that... :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard and shouldn't that blog post be changed then?? It doesn't say anywhere that Stack Overflow is its DBA...

Comment: Cheers, I copied the official reply by SE employee, not 100% sure myself, but sounds like it's related to something legal, or trademark.

Comment: As for mentioning this in blog, you can ask CKY in a comment reply. :)

Comment: @shadow done :)